# Derivative as distribution

Tags: partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory, weak-derivatives

We consider the Heaviside function $H(x)$.

$H'(0)$ doesn't exist. The derivative exists if we define $H$ as a distribution

$$H: \phi \to \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} H(x) \phi(x) dx= \int_0^{+\infty} \phi(x) dx$$

$\partial{H}$ is a function $\partial{H}: \phi \to \langle \partial{H}, \phi \rangle=- \langle H, \phi' \rangle=-\int_0^{+\infty} \phi'(x) dx=\phi(0)= \langle \delta, \phi \rangle$

Thus, $H'(x)=\delta(x)$.

If $f$ is smooth, I want to show that $(fH)'=f(0) \delta+ H f'$.

That's what I have tried so far:

$$(fH)(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
f(x) &, x>0 \\ 
0 &, x \leq 0 
\end{matrix}\right.$$

We consider $fH$ as a distribution $$fH: \phi \to \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} (fH)(x) \phi(x) dx=\int_0^{+\infty} f(x) \phi(x) dx$$

Then $$(fH)': \phi \to \langle (fH)', \phi\rangle=- \langle fH, \phi' \rangle=-\int_{0}^{+\infty} f(x) \phi'(x) dx=-f(0) \phi(0)+ \int_{0}^{+\infty} f'(x) \phi(x) dx $$

How can we continue in order to show that the latter is equal to $f(0) \delta+ H f'$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you have
$$
-\int_{0}^{+\infty} f(x) \phi'(x) dx={\color{red}+}f(0) \phi(0)+ \int_{0}^{+\infty} f'(x) \phi(x) dx=f(0) \phi(0)+ \langle Hf',\phi\rangle,
$$
that is,
$$
-\int_{0}^{+\infty} f(x) \phi'(x) dx=\langle f(0) \delta+  Hf',\phi\rangle.
$$

Comment: Right, now it's fine.

Comment: I want to show that $\frac{\partial{E}}{\partial{t}}-\Delta E=\delta(t,x) $.

So it suffices to show that  $\langle \frac{\partial{E}}{\partial{t}}-\Delta E, \phi \rangle=\phi(0,0)$.

I have shown so far that $\langle \frac{\partial{E}}{\partial{t}}-\Delta E, \phi \rangle=\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \frac{1}{(2 \sqrt{\pi \epsilon})^n} e^{-\frac{|x|^2}{4 \epsilon}} \phi(\epsilon,x) dx $

How could we continue?

Comment: You should take $\phi(x)$, not $\phi(\epsilon, x)$. Then estimate the difference between your integral and the same with $\phi(x)$ replaced by $\phi(0)$: you can separate the integral say in the regions $\|x\|\le\sqrt\epsilon$ and the complement.

Comment: So you mean that we should show that $\langle \frac{\partial{E}}{\partial{t}}-\Delta E, \phi(x) \rangle=\phi(0)$ ? Why would this imply that $\frac{\partial{E}}{\partial{t}}-\Delta E=\delta(t,x)$ ?